# ASP file not running

Tags: iis, asp-classic

Hey I just wrote a Hello World code for ASP. But it is not compiling using IIS . When I try to access it using localhost/path_to_folder/xyz.asp

It shows the entire code as it is ..

Can anyone tell me whats the problem?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this Step by Step:

1. Go to control panel
2. Windows features on/off
3. Tick this features:

   3.a) Internet Information Service>Web management tools>IIS6 Management Compatibility

   3.b) Internet Information Service>Web management tools>IIS Management Console

   3.c) Internet Information Service>Worldwide web services>Application dev. features>ASP

   3.d) Internet Information Service>Worldwide web services>Application dev. features>ISAPI Extentions

**These settings are necessary. If still doesnt work, Let me know for further settings.**

Answer (score 0):

Classic ASP support isn't installed by default on recent versions of IIS so you'll need to install it via the "Turn Windows features on and off" Control Panel, or with the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).

Comment: But the problem is that when I use my xampp, since both are accessed in the browser through localhost/..... it simply says not found..and when i put my apache off it shows broken link. I have already checked IIS in control panel. Nothing working ... Please help

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing via the web server built into Visual Studio?  If so, it won't work.  That server doesn't support .asp, only .as?x files.